# Wrong DocumentRoot being used in Apache Docker container

Tags: apache, docker

Even though I specified a `DocumentRoot` in my configuration, I need to specify the sub folder included in the `DocumentRoot` to load URLs.

- Works: 192.168.2.35/default/index.html
- Doesn't work, but is wanted: 192.168.2.35/index.html

Output of `docker exec -it apache httpd -S` showing virtual host loaded:

```
me@server:/var/www/html$ docker exec -it apache httpd -S
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.2.35:80        localhost (/usr/local/apache2/conf/enabled-sites/default.conf:10)
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/proc/self/fd/2"
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/apache2/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "/usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

My volumes for the Docker container:

```
"Binds": [
    "/var/www/html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs:rw",
    "/etc/apache2/conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf:ro",
    "/var/log/apache2:/usr/local/apache2/logs:rw"
],
```

`default.conf`:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/default>
        Options -Indexes 
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 192.168.2.35:80>
        ServerName localhost

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/default

        LogLevel debug

        ErrorLog logs/error.default.ca.log
        CustomLog logs/access.default.ca.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP specified for the virtualhost doesn't match the IP used by Docker.

Using `*:80` in the virtualhost instead fixes it.